# Multiple Spring Boot Unit Test Classes Run Successfully in IntelliJ IDEA but Fail with 'mvn test

Tags: spring-boot, maven, unit-testing

**My project directory is organized as follows:**

[image]

**Environment**

jdk8

spring boot 2.7.1

junit-jupiter 5.8.2

**Code**

QuestionControllerTest.java: A test class annotated with @SpringBootTest.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(classes = QuestionnaireApplication.class)
class QuestionControllerTest {

    protected static RedisServer REDIS_SERVER;

    private static MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Inject
    private QuestionController questionController;

    @Inject
    private QuestionnaireAnswerMapper questionnaireAnswerMapper;

    @Inject
    private QuestionnaireService questionnaireService;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        log.info("redis server start");
        REDIS_SERVER = RedisServer.builder().port(16370).build();
        REDIS_SERVER.start();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(questionController).build();
    }

    @Test
    void selectQuestionnaire() throws Exception {

    。。。
    }

   
   

    @Test
    @Order(200)
    void selectUnAnswerQuestionnaire() {
    。。。
    }

    @Test
    @Order(300)
    void answerQuestionnaire() {
    。。。

    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterClass() {
        log.info("redis server stop");
        REDIS_SERVER.stop();
    }
```

QuestionApiTest.java: Another test class annotated with @SpringBootTest.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(classes = QuestionnaireApplication.class)
class QuestionApiTest {

    protected static RedisServer REDIS_SERVER;

    protected static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Inject
    private QuestionApiController questionApiController;

    @Inject
    private QuestionnaireService questionnaireService;

    @Inject
    private QuestionnaireAnswerMapper questionnaireAnswerMapper;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        log.info("redis server start");
        REDIS_SERVER = RedisServer.builder().port(16370).build();
        REDIS_SERVER.start();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(questionApiController).build();
    }

    @Test
    void selectQuestionnaire() throws Exception {

        String userCode = "123123";

        String orderId = "1231231231231231";
        CreateQuestionnaireReqDto createQuestionnaireReqDto = new CreateQuestionnaireReqDto();
        int typeId = QuestionnaireTypeEnum.FEI_TU_T0.getTypeId();
        createQuestionnaireReqDto.setTypeId(typeId);
        createQuestionnaireReqDto.setUserCode(userCode);
        createQuestionnaireReqDto.setOrderId(orderId);
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/questionnaire")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(createQuestionnaireReqDto))
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(builder)
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        String responseContent = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        RespMsg respMsg = objectMapper.readValue(responseContent, RespMsg.class);
        Assertions.assertTrue(respMsg.isSuccess());

        QuestionnaireAnswer questionnaireAnswer = questionnaireAnswerMapper.selectNeedAnswerQuestionnaire(userCode, typeId, orderId);
        log.info("questionnaireRspDto = {}", questionnaireAnswer);
        Assertions.assertTrue(Objects.nonNull(questionnaireAnswer));
    }


    @AfterAll
    public static void afterClass() {
        log.info("redis server stop");
        REDIS_SERVER.stop();
    }

}
```

both of the two annotation with SpringBootTest load content QuestionnaireApplication

**Issue Description:**

Both of these classes run successfully when executed individually in IntelliJ IDEA. However, when I attempt to run them collectively using 'mvn test,' I encounter failures. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   QuestionControllerTest.answerQuestionnaire » IllegalState Failed to load Appli...
[ERROR]   QuestionControllerTest.selectQuestionnaire » IllegalState Failed to load Appli...
[ERROR]   QuestionControllerTest.selectUnAnswerQuestionnaire » IllegalState Failed to lo...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I observed that when I merge the @Test methods from both classes into a single class, leaving only one class annotated with @SpringBootTest, the mvn test command runs successfully.

**Question**
Why is this happening? How can I resolve the issue of mvn test failure?

I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance.